# Arabic words are displayed separately only in Google Chrome - MacOS

Tags: html, css, font-family

I am developping a php website in arabic, I tested it in chrome, firefox and ie, it works fine. The client uses his Mac laptop to see the website, all words were separated. Other arabic websites on his chrome are displayed normally. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide an URL or at least a screenshot?

Comment: this is the link: sacm.atwebpages.com

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on latest OS X.

[image: Safari 7.0.2]
[image: Chrome 32.0.1700.77]
[image: Firefox 26.0]

Comment: In the second screenshot, the words are detached in letters. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Ah, now I got it. There seems to be a problem with your _Tunisia_ font in Chrome.  I disabled it in Devtools and the ligatures got  displayed properly.

Comment: Is there a way that i can add a plugin to chrome or a meta tag in my code to let the font appears properly?

Comment: I don't know, but what about using an alternative font like Geeza Pro?

Comment: The client is requesting the "Tunisia" font. Thanks Lars for your time. If you figure out or anyone have a solution, i need it so much & thx.